# Slick-Carousel autoplay starting when element in view

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I use the autoplay function in slick slider to change the slides every 10 seconds:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function () {
    jQuery('.slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        arrows: false, 
        dots: true, 
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 10000,
        speed: 1500
    });
});
```

The autoplaySpeed function starts counting when the page is loaded but i want to start the count just when the slick-element comes into view. How is it possible to load the slider on page load but start autoplay when the element arrives in the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `autoplay: false` when you initialize your slideshow and then when the slideshow enters the viewport, you can set the option to `true`.

```
$('.slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplay', true);
```

To detect when the element comes into view, see: [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)